# Gem clobbers routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rubygems

I followed the gem tutorial/example here: https://github.com/krschacht/rails_3_engine_demo

So, I cloned the repo, renamed all the files/modules/objects to my own gem.

I also have a test app, to exercise the new gem. In the exercise gem file I have:

```
gem 'mynewgem', :path => '../mynewgem/'
gem 'rails_3_engine_demo', :path => '../rails_3_engine_demo'
```

(if you look at the demo, you'll see that everything is called 'cheese').

I run bundle install (all good) then rake routes and this is my output:

```
        cheese        /cheese(.:format)             {:controller=>"cheese/widgets", :action=>"index"}
cheese_widgets GET    /cheese/widgets(.:format)     {:controller=>"cheese/widgets", :action=>"index"}
 cheese_widget GET    /cheese/widgets/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"cheese/widgets", :action=>"show"}
```

so, any ideas why the routes of the other gem gets clobbered?

Another question, do gems commonly have their own routes inside their respective gems? Or would be something the user of the gem should edit in their routes.rb file?